# Is it posible to return javascript function from golang struct?

Tags: javascript, function, go, struct

Example below is a golang struct

```
type Column struct {
        Data            string      `json:"data"`
        Title           string      `json:"title"`
        Type            string      `json:"type"`
        Class           string      `json:"class"`
        Visible         bool        `json:"visible"`
        Render          template.JS `json:"render"`
}

func (c *Column) SetValue() {
        // code below is flexible depend on condition but here i keep it simple.
        c.Render = template.JS(`function(data, type, row) { if(type === 'display'){ return $.fn.dataTable.render.text().display(data);} return data;}`);
}
```

Here is Javascript in golang template

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        console.log({{.Columns}}, wantedobj);
    });
</script>
```

Here is chrome developer tools.

- left list is format value from struct above.
- right list is format that I want.

[image]

on ***render*** is there any posible way to get javascript function instead of string? (please see **render** at right picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `template.JS` is correct. Your problem is that in HTML templates, values are escaped based on [contexts](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#hdr-Contexts):

> At parse time each {{.}} is overwritten to add escaping functions as necessary.

Inside `<script>` tags, struct values such as `{{.Columns}}` are rendered as JSON. Now, since [`template.JS`](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#JS) is simply a defined type over `string`, when you marshal `Columns` as JSON, the field `Render` keeps its string representation.

If you print `Render` directly, it will appear as unquoted Javascript:

```
console.log({{.Columns.Render}}); // unescaped JS function
```

Now you might think of implementing `MarshalJSON` on `Columns` to render `Render` as unescaped Javascript, but that wouldn't be valid JSON anymore. Function is not a JSON data type. It can only be a string. An option is to use `text/template` package instead, but it won't escape **anything** anymore. Or construct the Javascript object using the single fields:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        const foo = {
            data: {{.Columns.Data}},
            render: {{.Columns.Render}}
        }
        console.log(foo);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I recommend against templating  to deliver data to javascript, NightOwl.  It's difficult to do the escaping properly, and hard to debug.  I much prefer to write static javascript and use an API call to pull data from the backend.